# Can we replace deterministic part of alternative turing machine with some other equivalent machines?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, time-complexity, time-hierarchy

I'm sorry if it is a low level question but I am so confusing.

If $DTime(n)\subseteq \Sigma_2Time(n^{0.2})$ then $DTime(n) \subseteq \Sigma_2DTime(n^{0.2})$

Is this true that $\Sigma_2DTime(n^{0.2})\subseteq\Sigma_2\Sigma_2Time((n^{0.2})^{0.2})=\Sigma_4Time(n^{0.04})$

I picked up DTime in alternative machine and replaced it with $DTime(n)\subseteq \Sigma_2Time(n^{0.2})$  and replacing  n with $n^{0.2}$.

Comment: This won’t work. The inner machine has still access to the original input of length $n$, hence it runs in time $n^{0.2}$, not $n^{0.04}$. (Also, all this makes any sense only in a model with random-access input; otherwise time $n^{0.2}$ is the same as time $O(1)$.)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/41350/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/96147/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to work on what $(0.2)^2$ is before you go any further.

Comment: I'm sorry I think it is 0.04 in the question it is $(n^{0.2})^{0.2}$.If we suppose $DTime(n) \subseteq \Sigma_2Time(n^{0.2})$ then $DTime(n^{0.2}) \subseteq \Sigma_2Time(n^{0.04})$ I want to calculate $\Sigma_2DTime(n^{0.2})$  so I picked $DTime(n^{0.2})$ and replaced with  $\Sigma_2Time(n^{0.04})$ and I recived to $\Sigma_2DTime(n^{0.2})\subseteq\Sigma_2\Sigma_2Time(n^{0.04})=\Sigma_4Time(n^{0.04})$.  I want  to know is this correct? thanks alot.